# The proper way to add multi-environment variables to my npm start script?

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, npm-scripts

what is the proper way to add multi-environment variables to my npm start script?

Right now I am using this (3 environment variables here) and it looks ugly:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV='development' DB='mongo' PASS='123456' node --inspect ./bin/www"
  },
```

---- update ----

Using dotenv is one way to go. I also found another method to do it when trying to find an answer to my other question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47457384/301513, i.e. using [per-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/per-env)

I leave my question here to see if I can get other methods.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use dotenv module. You can find it on npm.

Then all you need is to create a `.env` file.

1. Create `.env` file

   ```
   NODE_ENV=development
   PORT=3000
   ```
2. Inside your package.json

   ```json
   {
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node -r dotenv/config ./bin/www"
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know dotenv exists.