# Why does my node container ignore the environment variable I set in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

In my docker-compose.yml, I set environment NODE_ENV

```
node2:
    image: ...
    environment:
     - "NODE_ENV=production"
```

My Dockerfile,

```
FROM node:latest
... //all the ususal stuff
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My npm,

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development node --inspect ./bin/www"
  },
```

But when I run docker-compose up, I found the nodejs code still runs in development, not in production. Why is that?

My second question is what is the proper way to achieve what I want to do here, when running my nodejs without docker, i.e. using `npm start`, I want it to run in development mode, but running docker in production mode?

---- update -----

For my first question now I understand it is my `npm start` overwrote NODE_ENV=production in docker-composer.yml not the other way around.

But for my second question, I am still looking for an easy solution.

Thanks for the answers I got so far.

Comment: Is it not supposed to be run in `development` as you override your `NODE_ENV` in your start script?

Comment: Maybe I got it all wrong :$.  I had thought the environment variable in docker-compose.yml will override the setting in Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

This article "[Working with Environment Variables in Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js.html)" gave me some thought.

So I first used [if-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/if-env) as it suggested and my `npm script` looks liked this,

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
    "start:dev": "DEBUG=dummy-app:* node --inspect ./bin/www",
    "start:prod": "node ./bin/www"
   }
```

But as https://github.com/ericclemmons/if-env/issues/6 said and more importantly I need to an easy way to set environment variables and overwrite them if necessay now I am using [per-env](https://github.com/ericclemmons/per-env/) and my `npm script` looks like this,

```
  "per-env": {
    "production": {
      "DBPASS":"superman", //this can be overwrote again 
    },
    "development":{
      "DBPASS":"batman",
      "DEBUG":"dummy-app:*",
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start":"per-env",
    "start:development": "node --inspect ./bin/www",
    "start:production": "node ./bin/www"
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

My first guess would be to have different `npm script` entries in your `package.json` for the different environments like `start` for production and `inspect` for developping/debugging - with according `ENV_VARS`.

But if you would like to stick with one `script` for all, then you might consider using a `bash` default value like `${parameter:-default}` for `NODE_ENV` if it has not been set (by Docker):

```
"start": "NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:-development} node --inspect ./bin/www"
```

References:
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html
https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/shell-variables-in-npm-scripts/

Comment: See my answer (after spending several hours in searching :$)